# Unable to get results from related documents in FastAPI-Users and Beanie

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I have a couple of models:

```
class Message(Document):
    phone: str
    message_body: str
    user: Indexed(PydanticObjectId)

    class Settings:
        name = "Message"


class User(BeanieBaseUser[PydanticObjectId]):
    messages: Optional[List[Link[Message]]]
```

They have a relationship using Beanie Link.
The Message model is a custom Model and User is the default of FastAPI-Users.

When I save a record with insert() on a Message that is the child model, it does not establish a relationship with the parent. Returning the dict with null messages field.
Any idea what could be the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is with `fetch_link`

```
@app.get("/messages")
async def list_messages(user: User = Depends(current_active_user)):
    await user.fetch_link(User.messages)
    return user.messages
```

Checkout the response from FastAPI-Users creator
https://github.com/fastapi-users/fastapi-users/discussions/1006#discussion-4101669